# Neo4j and Cypher: set labels from collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have bunch of labels as input. I want to iterate through and set it. The following code does give the error:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WITH collect(n.lab) as labels
FOREACH (x IN labels | SET n:x);
```

When I execute, I get the following message:

> WARNING: Variable `n` not defined (line 3, column 28 (offset: 73))
>   "FOREACH (x IN labels | SET n:x)"

Comment: WITH n, .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have forgot to pass `n` to the next context. That is:

```
WITH n, collect(n.lab) as labels
```

Second, you cannot set labels this way, with pure Cypher. When you do `SET n:x` you are adding a label `x` in the node `n`. But you can do it using the [APOC procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) `apoc.create.addLabels`, this way:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WITH n, collect(n.lab) as labels
call apoc.create.addLabels(n, labels) yield node
return *
```

Comment: Bruno was quicker to answer.
For next readers, my example code 

CREATE (n:Toto {lab:["titi","tutu","tata"]})
MATCH (n:Toto) CALL apoc.create.addLabels(n, n.lab) YIELD node RETURN node
Check with MATCH (n:titi) RETURN n

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  
I have trouble invoking the procedure.
WARNING: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.create.addLabels` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

I downloaded the jar file and put it in plugins directory.
added plugins directory in neo4j.config
added procedures unrestricted
dbms.directories.plugins=plugins
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*

what am i missing?

Comment: Bruno - Not yet. Trouble invoking the procedure.

Comment: @sranga change the line `dbms.directories.plugins=plugins` to `dbms.directories.plugins=/plugins`. That is: you forgot a `/`

Comment: @sranga also you should restart neo4j service... Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Bruno, Adding /plugins did not work. In fact i tried full path with no luck. Btw, I am using it in linux. I invoke neo4j-shell the folllowing way:

./../neo4j-enterprise-3.3.2/bin/neo4j-shell -path /home/srangara/work/Neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-3.3.2/data/databases/graph.db -file loadcsv.cypher.

Comment: @sranga neo4j-shell is deprecated. Use [Cypher Shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/) instead.